# How did Latika get her scar?

Tags: slumdog-millionaire

In SlumDog Millionaire, how did Latika get the scar on her face?

The last train dance scene reveals the scar on her face.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they cut her face after they snatch her from the train station and force her into the car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thugs slashed her face after snatching her from the train station. From her [Wiki page](http://hero.wikia.com/wiki/Latika):

> One day, Jamal confesses his love for Latika after he finds her and Salim with Javed. After a while, Latika escapes and meets Jamal at the train station but is recaptured by Javed's thugs. **Salim slashes her face with a knife as punishment.**